# Ошибка Android studio Gradle project refresh failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Только установил android studio 2.2, создал новый проект и сразу же вывалилась ошибка

> Error:Process 'command '/home/artempopov/Programs/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`'

Система Ubuntu 16.04. JRE 1.8.0. OpenJDK. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем дело.

UPD:
После переустановки на 64-битную систему ошибка исчезла. В системных требованиях так и указано, что необходим 64-битный дистрибутив. Вопрос закрыт, всем спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Clean/Rebuild проекта пробовали делать?

Comment: Да, не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

*Cначала попробуйте это:* Надо в **build.gradle** прописать

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.am.android"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 23
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    jumboMode = true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Скорее всего это. Вы, видимо, изменили что-то в **build.gradle**
*Если не помогло.*
У Вас может быть прописан код на подобии:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'

compile files('libs/spotify-web-api-android-master-0.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.3.0.jar')
```

Надо закомментировать.

Comment: К сожалению удаление gradle не помогло. JDK стоит.

Comment: изменил ответ. @АртёмПопов